# NoMethodError in UserController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep getting the following error on my app from 7.2.1 on Michael Hartl Ruby Rails tutorial.  For some reason it is not accepting a nil @user field in the signup form.

```
undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff87141aef8>:0x007ff870cf0d30>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign up") %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**User_controller.rb**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :user

  get 'user/new'

  root 'static_pages#home'

  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'

  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'

  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'

  get 'signup' => 'user#new'
```

Comment: Try resources :users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `resources :user` to `resources :users` and define the index action in the controller by adding

```
def index
end
```

Comment: Thanks amazing! Been staring at this for ages!!

Comment: It's now given rise to a further problem in that my show method doesn't work.It gives me the 'i'm sorry something went wrong' screen Started POST "/users" for 193.63.239.133 at 2015-03-04 11:12:17 +0000
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UsersController):

Comment: It's now given rise to a further problem in that my show method doesn't work.It gives me the 'i'm sorry something went wrong' screen

Comment: I can see in the error message that you're sending a POST request, when the show method is a GET. If you're clicking a link in a view to get to your show, can you show me that view?